# Upgrading Git-LFS whilst keeping Git the same version?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-lfs

For various reasons I need to keep the Bitbucket and associated Git version i'm running the same version as it is now - however I want to patch for the Git-LFS vulnerability. I couldn't find any information on if I can upgrade my version of Git-LFS to the latest patched version i.e v2.13.2 whilst keeping my Git version at 2.16.2.windows.1 (current Git-LFS is 2.3.4.0).
The environment is Windows.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works fine. Just tested on a virgin Windows 7 x64 in Virtual Box.
Installed Git 2.16.2 and Git-LFS 2.13.2.
[image]

Then cloned my work repo with 2 big submodules (all 3 with LFS enabled) and it worked without errors:
[image]